# Non-numeric argument to binary operator, CSV

Tags: r, binary, operators

I've seen that other people before were already struggling with this, however I didn't manage to solve my problem with those posts. I get the error 'Non-numeric argument to binary operator'. The following reproducible example works:

```
x=rnorm(1000)+sin(c(1:1000)/100)#random data+ sinus superimposed
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

plot(x)# plot random data
plot(filter(x,rep(1/100,100)))
plot(x-filter(x,rep(1/100,100)))

# variances of variable, long term variability and short term variability
var(x)
var(filter(x, rep(1/100,100)),na.rm=T)
var(x-filter(x, rep(1/100,100)),na.rm=T)
```

However, I of course want to use my own dataset, it's a csv, and this is when the error occurs. It must have something to do with the data format, because when I export the random data to csv:

```
x=rnorm(1000)+sin(c(1:1000)/100)#random data+ sinus superimposed
write.csv(x,"dat.csv")
```

and then try to read in dat.csv

```
y <- read.csv("dat.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(y)
plot(filter(y,rep(1/100,100)))
plot(y-filter(y,rep(1/100,100)))
```

[...] I get the error

```
Error in x - filter(x, rep(1/100, 100)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
Calls: plot
In addition: Warning message:
In plot(x - filter(x, rep(1/100, 100))) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.ts") for "-"
Execution halted
```

Why are the values not numeric? I don't get it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the post a little so the `x` variable wasn't reused for the input & output.  The value from `read.csv()` is now `y`.  Notice its a [`data.frame`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html), while `x` is an ordinary [`numeric` vector](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html).

To get the 2nd set of graphs to behave like the first set, extract the first vector from `y` (called `y1` below), then pass that vector to the dplyr functions.

```
y <- read.csv("dat.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y1 <- y$x # Extract the first column
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(y1)
plot(filter(y1,rep(1/100,100)))
plot(y1-filter(y1,rep(1/100,100)))
```